# How can i make ros IOT capable?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to sent my sensor readings to another pc using cloud, Is it possible in ROS ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285775/how-can-i-make-ros-iot-capable?/) by [ARUN T S](https://answers.ros.org/users/32369/arun-t-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the [mqtt-bridge](https://github.com/groove-x/mqtt_bridge)

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0